# how can I find row index number in data frame column?

Tags: r

I have the following data frame.How can I find the row index number for `a=1,3,7`

```
df  
a   b
1   5
2   6
3   4
7   8
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `%in%` to get a logical index

```
which(df$a %in% c(1,3,7))
```

Or with `match`

```
 match(c(1,3,7), df$a)
```

Comment: may be better use `which` ? ( "row index number" not always equals "row.names")

Comment: @Batanichek  Yes, you are right.  I was thinking that the OP wanted row names